# Maximum length of generated hash when using password_hash?

Tags: php, password-encryption

I'm using

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

to encrypt passwords to store in a database. As I read, there's no length limit on generated hashes, but I need to know the maximum length so I can use it to define the field in my database which can fit all password hashes (in a worst case scenario).

If I put a limit of 20 characters for the password in plain text, how long will the `password_hash()` result will be?

Comment: The recommendation is to create a `VARCHAR(255)`.... password_hash currently creates a 60 character hash than you need to store, but that is subject to change in the future if the underlying algorithm changes. Hash length is completely unaffected by the length of the password, but why limit passwords to 20 characters?

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Comment: `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, or `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` => 60.
`PASSWORD_ARGON2I` => about 96 (depend on `time_cost` and `memory_cost`).
`PASSWORD_ARGON2ID` => about 97 (depend on `time_cost` and `memory_cost`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [`password_hash` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

> The following algorithms are currently supported:
>
> `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0).
>   Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and
>   stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of
>   the result from using this identifier can change over time. **Therefore,
>   it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can
>   expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).**
>
> `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` - Use the `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` algorithm to create the hash.
>   This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier. **The result will always be a 60 character string**, or FALSE
>   on failure.

Therefore, using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, the result of `password_hash` will be a 60 character string.

Comment: Please note as of PHP 8.0.0 `password_hash()` no longer returns FALSE on failure (it's in the official documentation).

Answer (score 3):

The result of BCrypt will always be a 60 character string. Limitless is only the input for the function, that means you do not (and should not) set a limit to the entered passwords.

Actually BCrypt internally uses only about 72 characters, but it accepts passwords of any length.

If you want to use the function in its future proof form like this (notice the PASSWORD_DEFAULT)...

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

...then you should make your database field bigger. Newer PHP versions may replace BCrypt with another default hash algorithm, which may generate longer hashes.