# PHP password_verify PDO returns false every time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, verify

I have this PHP code. The variable $password has the right password static assigned (no user input to validate).

$data['password'] returns the right hash too, when printing it out with echo.

But somehow the password_verify function doesnt work in this function. When I'm using it manually with the same inputs it workes fine.

Maybe there is something wrong with the PDO query, but I have no idea what.

```
    $this->mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
    $this->mysql->bind(':username', $username);
    $data = $this->mysql->single(); 

    if($this->mysql->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        echo $data['password'];
        if(password_verify($password, $data['password']))
        {

            echo "yees!";

        }else{
            $this->user_error = true;
        }       
    }else{
        $this->user_error = true;           
    }
```

Comment: What datatype/size if your password column in your database?

Comment: Show us what values you have. We cannot verify what "the right" data is. How have *you* verified that the data is "right"?

Comment: @mark-baker it's text

Comment: @deceze It tried it with the same values manually and directly without PDO the input is "123456" and the hash is "$2y$10$HRnsvpIpuIxnSAXXezm/D.prUD6COgz/C0TUzDUF0d.UIcXZw/MdS"

Comment: So $data['password'] can't be the hash, or $password can't be '123456'. What do you see if you do `var_dump($password)` and `var_dump($data['password'])` rather than just echoing them? I'm suspecting you've got something like a space or newline characters on the end of one or the other of them.

Comment: @user3747630 - And the length of the field? Is it long enough to hold the full value of the hash?

Comment: @MarkBaker MySQL's TEXT type is 64K long. So in fact, the field is preposterously long for a password hash; the [recommended storage for a password_hash value is 255 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21479715/300836).

Comment: @MarkBarker I allrady changed it to varchar 255. I'll post the output of vat_dump tomorrow I'm on my mobile phone now.

Comment: @Mark Here is the output from var_dump: `array(5) { ["id"]=> string(32) "7" ["firstname"]=> string(32) "Max" ["lastname"]=> string(32) "Mustermann" ["username"]=> string(32) "MaMustermann" ["password"]=> string(64) "$2y$10$HRnsvpIpuIxnSAXXezm/D.prUD6COgz/C0TUzDUF0d.UIcXZw/MdS" }´ 



´string(64) 
"$2y$10$HRnsvpIpuIxnSAXXezm/D.prUD6COgz/C0TUzDUF0d.UIcXZw/MdS"` 

I really have no idea why it isn't working as it should

Comment: So the `$password`, which you're trying to verify, is already hashed...?!

Comment: No, `$password` is the user input. `$data['password']` is hashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.
There where some whitespaces in the array, but I haven't got any idea where they came from.
So I jused the `trim()` function to remove these whitespaces and now everything works properly.

Thanks for quick help!